# Understanding the relationship between the Black-Scholes formula and a replicating portfolio

Tags: black-scholes, replication, self-study, put

I'm self-studying and I'm considering the below example. The specific example is not especially relevant, but I included it for reference.

I'm trying to understand the relationship between a replicating portfolio and the Black-Scholes equation.

It is my understanding that a replicating portfolio for a put involves short selling stock and lending money. There would be a positive cash flow of $Se^{-\delta T} N(-d_1)$ and a negative cashflow of $Ke^{-rT} N(-d_2).$

However, the Black-Scholes formula for a put is: $P = Ke^{-rT}N(-d_2) - Se^{-\delta T} N(-d_1)$.

This formula suggests that a long position in a put is a *positive* cashflow of $Ke^{-rT} N(-d_2)$ and a *negative* cashflow of $Se^{-\delta T} N(-d_1)$.

So wouldn't the replicating portfolio create a *short* position put, while the Black Scholes formula provides a *long* position put (since the signs are swapped comparing the replicating portfolio to the Black Scholes formula for a put)?

Should examples like the one below clarify what position the put is in?

Basically I'm looking for clarification on the signs of the terms in the formula.

[image]

Comment: I think you should look for a better book. https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Stochastic-Calculus-Financial-Mathematics/dp/1584886269

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is my understanding that a replicating portfolio for a put involves short selling stock and lending money.

You cannot statically replicate an option. So this is not true in general, you'll need to re-balance your replicating portfolio (underlying + cash) dynamically if you want to replicate the option. This will imply sometimes buying stock and borrowing money.

> Basically I'm looking for clarification on the signs of the terms in the formula

Take the case $S=0$ and you'll see that the signs 
$$ P(K,T) = Ke^{-rT}N(-d_2) - Se^{-\delta T} N(-d_1) $$
are indeed correct since in that case you need to find $P(K,T) = K e^{-rT} > 0$, because the payout of a put option is: $\max(K-S_T,0)$.

Extending this idea:

- Call (Payoff $\to$ Price): $$\max({\color{blue}{+S}}_T{\color{blue}{-K}},0) \to C(K,T) = {\color{blue}{+S}}e^{-\delta T}\phi(d_1) {\color{blue}{-K}} e^{-rT}\phi(d_2)$$
- Put (Payoff $\to$ Price):  $$\max({\color{blue}{+K}}{\color{blue}{-S}}_T,0) \to P(K,T) = {\color{blue}{+K}}e^{-rT}N(-d_2) {\color{blue}{-S}} e^{-\delta T} N(-d_1)$$